# Regex ? does not work

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, browser

```
var contents = [];
contents.push('\r\n"use strict";');
contents.push('\n"use strict";');

var useStrictRegExp = /([^{]\r?\n)['"]use strict['"];/g;

for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; ++i) {
  var content = contents[i];
  console.log('before', content);
  var replaced = content.replace(useStrictRegExp, '$1');
  console.log('after', replaced);
}
```

This is meant to match `"use strict";` not inside a bracket.

But it seems to fail when not using Windows line endings. The output is:

```
before 
"use strict";
after 

before 
"use strict";
after 
"use strict";
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: You have a problem in `([^{]\r?\n)` part of code. I could not under stand what you were trying to do. Apart from that you need to escape `[\'\"]`

Comment: I think your sequence to match ' and " are wrong just check with : https://regex101.com/r/hU4vO7/10  and use grout 1 i.e. $1

Comment: @MegaMind Why do you need to escape quotes? That is a regex literal, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to @Sami's answer which is totally right (you check for a character that is followed by a carriage-return/new-line, and in your inputs that never happens), it looks more a need of a negative assertion rather than matching a single character. @Sami offered using a lookbehind, up to your question tags [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), you could only use a lookahead: `(?!{)`

```
/((?!{)\r?\n)['"]use strict['"];/g
```

```js
var contents = [];
contents.push('\r\n"use strict";');
contents.push('\n"use strict";');
contents.push('{\n"use strict";');

var useStrictRegExp = /((?!{)\r?\n)['"]use strict['"];/g;

for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; ++i) {
  var content = contents[i];
  console.log('before', content);
  var replaced = content.replace(useStrictRegExp, '$1');
  console.log('after', replaced);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you require a character that is not `{` to appear before `\n`. In the first one there is `\r` and then there is no `\r` but `\n` matches so everything is fine.

In the second one you get the first character which is `\n` and then there is no `\n` to match so it fails.

You probably want to use look behind to check that there is no `{` before, not require a character to exist. This won't really be enough to properly check the existence of `"use strict";` in proper context, but might be enough for you.